# Splicing from a weird DVD-format

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, ripping, mplayer

I have a DVD full of video clips. I want to exact only some of these clips. I tried to use mplayer/mencoder's nice feature of Edit Decision List (EDL). However, the video timer seems to constantly reset with each video clip (less than 20 seconds) and its EDL does not have a video clip number or anything like that.

I've tried using VLC to extract the video into an MPG file, but the same timer problem persists. What's a good way to splice out part of these clips from the DVD? I'm willing to write a small program in any language to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find it easier to rip the DVD contents to your HD, *then* use `mencoder` or `VLC` or `ffmpeg` directly on whichever `.VOB` files contain the clips you're interested in.